# Windows tells me to replace laptop battery, even though it works fine

Tags: windows-7, battery

My laptop suddenly started showing a cross symbol on the battery icon and Windows told me to replace it, but battery life is still stable. How do I remove the warning so that the icon returns back to normal?

Toshiba Satellite L640

Comment: What's your laptop model? Some manufacturers provide battery calibration utilities that can fix erroneous reporting of the battery's capacity.

Comment: If all else fails, running the machine until the battery is totally dead and then recharging it usually fixes it. You may need to do it twice.

Comment: Toshiba Satelit L640

Comment: It may be warning you that it's on it last legs and may fail at any point.  Battery time remaining is not the only metric it's measuring.   Aside from that, have you simply tried removing and reinserting the battery?  How old is the battery?

Comment: yes i have done, but nothing has changed. 1 year ago

Answer (score 4):

The thread [Windows 7 and the battery error "consider replacing your battery"](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itprohardware/thread/c6c043e6-eeb1-4e61-870d-896ca2f865d6)  on Microsoft TechNet is eleven pages long and filled with angry customers.

In brief:

- There is **no** way to turn this feature off manually, besides hiding the battery icon altogether.

  To do so:

  1. Right-click the battery icon.
  2. Click `Turn system icons on or off`.
  3. Do any of the following:

     - Choose `Power: off`.
     - 1. Click `Customize notification icons`.
       2. Uncheck `Always show all icons and notifications on the taskbar`.
       3. Choose `Power: Hide icons and notificaions`.
  4. Click `OK`.
- Microsoft blames the manufactures and their drivers. Try visiting [Toshiba Support](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/home.jsp) and downloading the latest drivers for your laptop.
- There always is the possibility that the displayed information is correct and your battery will die soon. Battery life decreases gradually under normal circumstances, so it's possbie you won't notice it before it's too late.

Comment: This is the only way I think which I do whenever my Windows start ti show this error...+1

Answer (score 1):

Windows 7 SP1 (Service Pack 1) adds the ability to simply disable the battery health warning by unselecting "Warn me if my battery may need replacement" checkbox. The option can be accessed by left-clicking on battery icon in the tray bar (if SP1 installed).

Answer (score 1):

I recently run into the same problem. I had just replaced the Battery and the HP Support Assistant was telling me everything was allright. But Windows 7 insisted with a red cross blinking on the battery icon. I tried many things none of that worked.

Randomly i opened the preferencies of the energy plans or however they are named in an English Windows 7. There i found out that the threshold for the battery state which tells the OS when to shut down due to lack of power, was in all plans, set to 99% instead of 10% and 5%. I reseted all energy plans and it was ok!

[Action on low Battery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AE4hW.png) [Battery - Advanced Preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqguq.png)
I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for sharing! 
Other people are simply using OP's method of fully draining the battery and then fully charging it. A couple of those cycles should fix the issue. 
Sometimes the OS gets confused and reports a bad batter when swapped when there's nothing bad with it. In these cases people usually just turn off the warning on the trey bar and continue using their computer normally.

Answer (score 0):

This issue and solution given [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2293330) is for hp laptops may help sometimes to your model also

**Cause :**
This issue occurs on some notebook models, which were not originally designed for Windows 7, because the system firmware (BIOS) incorrectly reports the Design Capacity of the battery to the operating system.

The "Consider replacing your battery" message is displayed when the Last Full Charge Capacity is less than 40% of the reported battery Design Capacity. Both the Last Full Charge Capacity and the reported battery Design Capacity are retrieved by Windows from the system ACPI firmware (BIOS).

**Solution :**
There is a Windows update that will remove the incorrectly reported battery message for only the affected systems. This update does not change any other behavior on the computer and will not change the actual battery life in any way. The update will only be offered if Windows Update detects that this update applies to your computer.

To obtain this update, visit this [Microsoft Windows Update website](http://update.microsoft.com)